# Nunit 2.6.2 Suite running twice instead of once

Tags: c#-4.0, testing, msbuild, nunit

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests.MyTest
{
public class SpikeSuite
{
    [Suite]
    public static IEnumerable Suite
    {
        get
        {
            var suite = new ArrayList
                {
                    new SpikeTest(),
                };
            return suite;
        }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class SpikeTest
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test setup");
    }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test fixture setup");
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test method");
    }
}
```

}

When I run the above mentioned fixture the output I get is:

Test fixture setup

.Test setup

Test method

Test fixture setup

.Test setup

Test method

How is it that the test setup, fixture setup and test method being executed twice?

Comment: What are you using to run your tests?

Comment: It runs as expected from the console when using nunit-console directly. Something is going wrong in msbuild.

Comment: In that case you would have to show how you are using msbuild to run the tests, can you show us the relevant sections of your msbuild file?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your test project is not referenced by another test project. In that case it will appear in two bin folders and be run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the NUnit Test Adapter and re-installing fixed this issue for me.

In Visual Studio > Tools > Extensions and Updates > Remove NUnit Test Adapter then re-install it